# Find the minima/maxima of the function with Lagrange multiplier

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, qcqp

> Find the minima and maxima of the function $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ under the constraint $y = x^2 - 9/2$. Use Lagrange multiplier method.

So we have the function $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ and I rewrite the constraint as $g(x,y) = x^2 - y - 9/2$. Then, I find the gradient vectors to be $\nabla f = (2x, 2y)$ and $\nabla g = (2y, -1)$. This gives me the system of equations

$$\begin{align}
2x &= \lambda 2x \\ 
2y &= -\lambda \\
y &= x^2 - 9/2
\end{align}$$

Solving the system of equations, I get $x \pm 4$. Plugging into $y = x^2 - 9/2$, I get the critical points $(4, 23/2)$ and $(-4, 23/2)$ or $(8, 23)$ and $(-8, 23)$.

So assuming I have done everything right, I have two critical points, but I am not sure where to go from here because I am confused how I am supposed to interpret this geometrically in my head what is going on.

Comment: of couse $(4,23/2), (-4,23/2)$ are the minima and $(8,23), (-8,23)$ are the maxima. You can see this by plugging them into $f(x,y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
L= x^2+y^2+ \lambda(y-x^2+9/2)
\end{eqnarray*}
This gives 
\begin{eqnarray*}
2x &= \lambda 2x \\ 
2y &= -\lambda \\
y &= x^2 - 9/2
\end{eqnarray*}
Solving these gives $\lambda=1$, $y=-1/2$, $x= 2$.
Which looks like a plausible minimum.

[image]

Comment: I guess by this graph, my points aren't even in the domain! I see how you got your x,y values too so I guess it makes sense